# SQL fixtures configurations

Tags: django, python-2.7

How do I insert initial values into my database tables after the first migrate in Django 1.7.

This is what I have tried.

> **myproject>myapp>sql>myModel.sql**

```
INSERT INTO myapp_myModel (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Smith');
```

> **myproject>myapp>models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

> **myproject>myapp>migrations>init.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models, migrations


def load_stores_from_sql():
    from myproject.settings import BASE_DIR
    import os
    sql_statements = open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myapp/sql/myModel.sql'), 'r').read()
    return sql_statements


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ('myapp', '0001_initial'),
    ]
    operations = [migrations.RunSQL(load_stores_from_sql())]
```

And also how do I go about Foreign Key fields?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your migration file should be named something like

```
myproject/myapp/migrations/0002_sql_fixtures.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i tried it and it seems to be working very well.